Get distinct values with collect_set SparkSQL
I have below data in hive table:
sample_data_sql.id  sample_data_sql.attr
1234                A1:481118_16-23  B1:2  A1:481118_16-48
5678                A1:1213274_7-44  B1:2  A1:1213274_16-49
1234                A1:665770_7-44   B1:2  A1:665770_62-01
5678                A1:665770_16-48  B1:2  A1:481118_16-49

This table has 2 columns id and attr. attr column contains tab separated values.
I want result with distinct values like below:
sample_data_sql.id  sample_data_sql.attr
1234                A1:481118_16-23  B1:2  A1:481118_16-48  A1:665770_7-44   A1:665770_62-01
5678                A1:1213274_7-44  B1:2  A1:1213274_16-49 A1:665770_16-48  A1:481118_16-49

I want to remove duplicate values while collecting this data with id
